# Selenium - Instagram bot: Follow a user after clicking a photo

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, jupyter

With my bot, I am planning a loop that does the following

- Search a hashtag (ex: instagram.com/running)
- Cick the first photo
- **Scrape username: if username is not in already following csv, then we would follow the user. If we are already following the user, then we skip this step** *(this is the step I cannot complete)*
- Like the photo, comment on the photo, click the arrow to the next photo, then repeat

Everything in my code is executed correctly however I've tried almost everything to get the follow and it won't click the button.

I'm getting the error: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (762, 202). Other element would receive the click: 
(Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)

This is the html code from Instagram:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Here is my code so far:
*Note: I've also used the Find element by Xpath and find element by class name method and it still didn't work*

```
#finding a specific hashtag
search_word = driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/' + #random.choice(hashtags) 
                         'fitness' + '/')
sleep(4)

first_sq = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a')
sleep(2)
first_sq.click()
sleep(5)

for i in range(10):
    #grabbing username
    username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span/a').text
    print(username)
    if username not in followinglist['0'].tolist():
        todays_users.append(username)
    else:
        #follow user and also add username to file
        follow_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Follow')]")
        follow_button.click()
        todays_users.append(username)
        sleep(randint(2,6))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='fr66n']").click() #like photo
    try:
        comment_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh')
        comment_box.click()
        comment_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh')
        comment_box.send_keys('Love this')
        sleep(3)
        comment_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        #grabbing username
        sleep(randint(2,6))
        driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
        sleep(randint(2,6))
    except:
        driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
        sleep(randint(2,6))
'''

My alternative solution is to scrape the usernames, then after liking and commenting on photos, I would have the bot go to the actual user's page and follow them from there. 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Bd9.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

With your current if-else-logic you will not achieve your goal. If i understand you correctly, you want to follow the user if `it's not` in the `followinglist`, otherwise just `pass` this step:

```
if username in followinglist['0'].tolist():
    pass
        
else:
    #follow user and also add username to file
    todays_users.append(username)
    follow_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Follow')]")
    follow_button.click()
    todays_users.append(username)
    sleep(randint(2,6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading username from CSV file. You can directly compare the text of the xpath and perform your actions accordingly.

1. Snippet of Following Element:

```html
<button class="sqdOP yWX7d     _8A5w5    " type="button">Following</button>
```

2. Snippet of Follow Element

```html
<button class="sqdOP yWX7d    y3zKF     " type="button">Follow</button>
```

Using the above information you can make your code to skip an already followed profile -

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/article/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button').text=='Following':
         
            print("Already Followed. And go to next post")
            sleep(2)
            driver.find_element_by_class_name("coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow").click()

 else:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/article/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button').click()
            print("started following")
            sleep(2)
```